# How to show the multi-line string in wrapper class in a VF page

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class, datatable

I am having a string field in a wrapper class which might contain several lines. And I am showing that field in an `<apex:dataTable>`. The code looks like this:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!childJobs}" var="Job">
    <apex:column>
         <apex:facet name="header">
                 time range
         <apex:facet>
         <span>{!Job.timePeriod}</span>
    <apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

The problem with this is the generated html will look like this:

```
<span>abc
def
ghi</span>
```

Which means the actual string shown on the screen will be abc def ghi without breaking into different lines. `<apex:outputField>` will automatically insert `<br>` in between lines. But outPutField doesn't work for wrapper class fields. And set the value attribute of the `<apex:column>` doesn't work as well.

One approach I can think of is using Javascript to analyze the string and insert `<br>` in between. But that doesn't sound very clear option to me. Is there any better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use CSS:

```
<span syle="white-space: pre">{!job.TimePeriod}</span>
```

This will wrap the line based on HTML-source line breaks.